# Effective ways to "Jazz up" and polish the UI of iOS 5 App

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, ios5, appearance

I've finished up my first iOS 5 app (and only third iOS app overall) and I'm wondering if anyone out there has any recommendations for adding that touch of class, polish, professionalism, etc. to a plain-vanilla iOS app. I've taken a look at an iOS 5 appearance tutorial but I don't find it extremely helpful. What do you do to add polish to your UI? For example, do you add a logo view in your UINavigationBar? Do you create custom UIKit control backgrounds/images? Do you remove rounded edges from controls? I would especially appreciate any input related to how you use the new Appearance options in iOS 5 to accomplish your UIX goals.

Comment: As a user, I find it nice that the UI on iOS is normalized to some extent. Adding a logo looks nice, but making a completely custom UI for your app may make it look less appealing (at least to me).

Comment: I agree, but as I user too I also find certain apps to look and feel more "polished" than others, and as somebody who is by no means a design expert I can't always pinpoint why I (or others) like these design choices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For inspiration, look at the apps featured by Apple in the App store.  Maybe hire an artist or designer familiar with iOS devices and their users (if you are not one yourself).  There seem to be lots of creative ways to potentially "delight" the user, customize things for your specific app's purpose or customer base, but still stay within the spirit of the HIG.

Comment: I can't afford a designer, so I'm looking for some more concrete suggestions... For example, I know there are things I can do in CSS to give a form input control a more "professional" feel, but those things do not always apply on the iPhone/iPad.